# TabBar is not visible on navigating into another UIViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I am navigating from **TabBarController** to another **UIViewController**.

```
aViewController.title = @"Product Name";
[self.tabBarController.navigationController pushViewController:aViewController animated:YES];
```

after navigating from the tabbar is not visible.

**So change code**

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aViewController animated:YES];
```

TabBar is visible but **< Back** button is not visible.

How to have tabbar and the default back button after navigating from tabbar?

Comment: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:aViewController animated:YES];` is the right way of doing this actually. Can you please check if the area where the back button use to be is tap-able or not? or may be you are setting back button to nil somewhere in code.

Comment: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:aViewController animated:YES];` is the right way of doing this actually. Can you please check if the area where the back button use to be is tap-able or not? or may be you are setting back button to nil somewhere in code.

Comment: As @UmairAamir correctly pointing out you must push from your navigationController and not from Tabviewcontoller's navigationVC

Answer (score 2):

I've just created a test project for this issue and you will see that it's working as expected.
https://github.com/Pei116/TabTest-iOS